# Python 3.6 - saving movie from real time plot - figure window in movie is moving upwards

Tags: python, plot, save, real-time, movie

I want to create a movie from a real time plot, where I constantly update data in the plot.
As the original code is too long and complex, I have replace the original data by a simpler code to focus on the issue with saving the movie.

1.) displaying the real time plot works fine

2.) saving the movie (without display real time plots) with the code below also works fine

3.) !!! However displaying the real time plotting and saving the movie at the same time produces a movie, where the figure window in the movie is slowly moving upwards !!!

What could be the reason this issue ???

A link of a screenshot of the movie:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xWcM.jpg

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as manimation

# we generate some synthetic data.
# we will make a list of X, Y lists.
# the original code use for generating data is too long and complex to show here
frames = []
frameNumber = 240  # we generate 240 different frames

for i in range(0, frameNumber):
    xData = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
    yData = np.sin(xData - i * 2.0 * np.pi / frameNumber)
    frames.append([xData, yData])
    print('frameNumber: ', i)

# now we put them together to make a movie! let's set up the movie writer
framerate = 60                           # 24 frames per second
# FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['avconv']
FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
metadata = dict(title='Wave Data', artist='Isaac Newton', comment='')
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=framerate, metadata=metadata)

# figure setup
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
firstFrameX, firstFrameY = frames[0]
l, = ax.plot(firstFrameX, firstFrameY, '-')

plt.ylabel(r'$x$ axis')
plt.xlabel(r'$y$ axis')
plt.xlim(0, 2 * np.pi)
plt.title(r'$\lambda = 2 \pi$')

# --- without displaying ---> comment next 2 lines
fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()
# ------------------------------------------------

# let's write to the file!
with writer.saving(fig, "anim.mp4", 100):
    for i in range(frameNumber):
        x, y = frames[i]
        l.set_data(x, y)

        # --- without displaying ---> comment next 4 lines
        ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
        ax.draw_artist(l)
        fig.canvas.update()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        # ------------------------------------------------
        writer.grab_frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using matplotlib.animation in Python 2.7.

For the first run in a fresh console, my movie would be fine, but if I would run the script again, the resulting movie would be moving upwards, just like in your screenshot.

Restarting the console solved the issue for me, but is not very convenient.

**Closing the figure, by adding plt.close(fig) at the end of my script, solved the problem for me.**

However, I still do not understand what exactly caused this in the first place.